# Filter record on a third party rest API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have to perform a search in millions of records.For this I have a restful service ( a third party api)  which gives 25 records in every single call. In every response I get an array of 25 records ,page number and total number of pages , i.e. if I give pagenumber=2 then next 25 records will come.That means to get all the data I will have to loop through till the last page number, make a call for each pageNumber and append the record in every call in the previous collection. The limitation is after 100 calls/minute the server (third party) starts rejecting the calls .And hence I never get the full data and eventually perform the required search.

I tried looping through all the pages.
I tried my hands on elastic search but I think I didnt get enough understanding to implement it.

```
public class EmpResponse
{
 public int Pages;
 public int PageNumber;
 public List<Employee> TotalRecords; 

    public Employee GetAllEmployees(string empId= "", string EmpName = "", string Manager = "")
    {
        string url = "thirdPartyurl?PageNumber=";
        string baseUrl = "thirdPartyurl?PageNumber=1";
        EmpResponse baseRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpResponse>(DataHelpers.GetDataFromUrl(baseUrl));
        for (int i = 2; i <= baseRes.Pages; i++)
        {
            EmpResponse currentRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmpResponse>(DataHelpers.GetDataFromUrl(url + i));
            if (currentRes != null)
                foreach (var item in currentRes.TotalRecords)
                {
                    baseRes.TotalRecords.Add(item);
                }
        }
        return baseRes;
    }
```

}

DataHelpers.GetDataFromUrl is used for calling the the url and for getting the response sepcific to that url.

now baseRes.Pages comes out to be 100000 (i.e baseRes.Pages =100000)that means 100000 pages that means 100000 calls. This is very much time taking and if the number of calls are more than 100 in a minute then the third party api starts rejecting the call.So how to get the whole data with this limitation and quickly.

Comment: Are those requests IP locked or API Key locked?

Comment: If the third party isn't allowing more calls per minute there is no code you could write to lift that restriction. And if you do (for example by using more servers with distinct IP addresses) you run the risk of your API key being blocked forever. Talk to third party or tell your customer to re-visit their requirements so you won't need all employees.

Comment: @SebastianWaldbauer : Its API key locked;

Comment: @rene : If I put some filter criterias even then the number of pages come out to be 104 , which is again 4 more than the allowed calls per minute

Comment: That API isn't a good fit for the requirements you have. Something has to give, either the API or your requirements. Keeping both the same is never going to fly.

Comment: @rene : Can it be solved through elastic search ??

Comment: Sure, if it isn't a problem the data is stale you could load all data upfront in Elastic Search and then point your app at the Elastic instance.

Comment: But  the issue is to get the data I will have to make multiple calls as previously, Is there by any means can we club multiple calls into one

Answer (score -1):

If tried to solve your problem with a bulk loading technique. Here's what i've done :) The interesting part is the python part, cuz the golang webserver is only the restricted thirdparty service :)

> Our HTTP Server which handles all requests...

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const (
    letterBytes   = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    letterIdxBits = 6                    // 6 bits to represent a letter index
    letterIdxMask = 1<<letterIdxBits - 1 // All 1-bits, as many as letterIdxBits
    letterIdxMax  = 63 / letterIdxBits   // # of letter indices fitting in 63 bits
)

var (
    src = rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
)

func generateData() string {
    b := make([]byte, 64)
    for i, cache, remain := 63, src.Int63(), letterIdxMax; i >= 0; {
        if remain == 0 {
            cache, remain = src.Int63(), letterIdxMax
        }
        if idx := int(cache & letterIdxMask); idx < len(letterBytes) {
            b[i] = letterBytes[idx]
            i--
        }
        cache >>= letterIdxBits
        remain--
    }

    return string(b)
}

func main() {
    apiKeys := make(map[string]int)

    apiKeys["abc"] = 0

    // run api clear
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                apiKeys["abc"] = 0
            case <-quit:
                ticker.Stop()
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    fmt.Printf("Loading basic http server\r\n")
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Printf("Got request: %s\r\n", r.URL.Query())

        // check api key
        if _, ok := apiKeys[r.URL.Query().Get("api")]; !ok {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        // check limitation
        if apiKeys[r.URL.Query().Get("api")] >= 100 {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        // get page number & generate data...
        data := generateData()

        io.WriteString(w, data)

        // save request
        apiKeys[r.URL.Query().Get("api")] = apiKeys[r.URL.Query().Get("api")] + 1

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        return
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil)
}
```

> Our requester
>   main.py

```
import requests
import time
"""
load data
"""

thirdPartyUrl = "http://localhost:1337/?api=abc"

def main():
    print("Loading program...")
    allPages = 100000
    currentPage = 0
    alreadyVisited = 0
    r = requests.session()
    res = r.get("{0}&PageNumber={1}".format(thirdPartyUrl, currentPage))

    if res.status_code == 200:
        print("Everything fine! Go and get other content...")
        while alreadyVisited <= allPages:
            if currentPage >= 99:
                time.sleep(6)
                currentPage = 0

            currentPage = currentPage + 1
            alreadyVisited = alreadyVisited + 1
            print("CurrentPage: {0} | Already visited: {1}".format(currentPage, alreadyVisited))

            data = r.get("{0}&PageNumber={1}".format(thirdPartyUrl, currentPage))
            print("Data: {0}".format(data.content))


main()
```

This is just a prototype :)